# PyPar2 changed?

Tags: installation, archive

In ubuntu 12.10 am checking compilations with
PyPar2.

But it changed from "Matrix of Solomon"
to "Reed Matrix of Solomon".

Is system corrupted or am I spooking myself ?

Comment: Where in the application did you noticee this change? Are there any failures?

Answer (score 1):

Was probably reading too quick or simply read it wrong.

Seems to be harmless and concerns the algorithm "matrix of solomon" resp.
"reed matrix of solomon" for checking codes with pypar2.

No there weren't any failures. I thought only the term "reed" was new ? but it is not ...